# React Native Call Functions one after another using time

Tags: react-native, function, time, call

I'm implementing and react-native application in this application I have two functions called `addDetails()` and `selectedItemDetailsAdd()` These two function called inside another function called `functionCombined()` when the user called the `functionCombined()` function using a button click it execute the `addDetails()` function. After that it execute the `selectedItemDetailsAdd()` function along with the `addDetails()` function for the first time. When the user click the button for the second time it execute only `selectedItemDetailsAdd()` function. because of the `if` condition.

**Here when the user calls the `functionCombined()` function for the very first time using a button click I want to execute that `addDetails()` function the same as before but the `selectedItemDetailsAdd()` should execute after *2 seconds*.**

Which means when the user calls the `functionCombined()` for the first time it should execute the `addDetails()` function and wait **2 seconds** and then it should execute the `selectedItemDetailsAdd()` function. Is there any way to implement it?

```
const addDetails = () => {
        {/* code */ }
    };

const selectedItemDetailsAdd = () => {
        {/* code */ }

    };



const functionCombined = () => {
        if (!buttonClicked) {
            addDetails();
            setButtonClicked(true);
        }
        selectedItemDetailsAdd();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `setInterval` API if you want to run every two seconds.
If you want to run it after once after 2 seconds you can do `setTimeout`